# Maven `project.basedir` not respected in distributionManagement

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a small project and I don't have a nexus or similar server, so I want to release the project locally, and then upload the jar manually to my web server.
For that I added to my pom:

```xml
   <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal-repository</id>
            <name>Internal Repository Releases</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

and I was expecting to have a `releases` at the project's root folder with the jar in it, but it seems that it's being put inside the target/checkout/ folder instead..

The project is located at `/Users/pgomez/sources/pweb/` and after running `mvn clean release:prepare release:perform -e`, in the logs I can see:

```
[INFO] Uploaded: file:///Users/pgomez/sources/pweb/target/checkout/releases/com/pweb/pweb/0.16/pweb-0.16.jar (2.0 MB at 14 MB/s)
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?
I was expeing it to be at:

`/Users/pgomez/sources/pweb/releases/com/pweb/pweb/0.16/pweb-0.16.jar`

Also, is this the correct approach? Should I simply grab the jar from my local `~/.m2/` folder instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the Maven release plugin, it makes a complete checkout of your project in `target/checkout` and builds the release from this checkout. During this build, the `${project.basedir}` is this `checkout` directory inside `target`.

If you want to run the Maven release plugin without having a Nexus/Artifactory, I would use a fixed directory on your system as a "repository", not something relative to the project dir.